# How do I change the file name before sending to upload_file.php?

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have this form here that allows a user to upload a file with the ext '.pdf' and upload it to the server. However, I would like to rename the file to the filename chosen in the 'Number' field. How would I go about doing that?

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Filename:<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
   Number:<input type="text" name="number" id="number" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For instance.... The user chooses the file 'test.pdf' and inserts 'file_name' in the Number field. I want to then have it send 'file_name.pdf' to the actual 'upload_file.php' script.

Any guidance would help,
Thanks

Comment: File name is not actually important, the file is uploaded in a binary format, with the file name as additional data. It's the "upload_file.php" script that manages the final file name. You could upload a 1234567890.pdf file, but upload_file.php could save it as abcde.pdf, for example, without any problem. Read about the `move_uploaded_file()` PHP function.

Answer (score 3):

The `$_FILES` superglobal array contain all required info about your file upload, so when you go to upload your file, `$_POST['number'] . '.pdf'` instead of the `name` attribute:

```
$upload_path = '/your/upload/location/' . $_POST['number'] . '.pdf';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path)) {
    // success
}
```

You'll probably want to do some character tests on the field to make sure somebody doesn't input `~!@#$%^&*(` etc... I would use `str_replace` to get rid of them and only leave letters, numbers and dashes myself.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file name before sending the POST request with the [`FormData` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
var file = $('#image-file').get(0).files[0];
var newFileName = file.name + "newName";
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, newFileName);

$.ajax({
  url: upload.php, // get the upload URL for the server
  success: function(fileData) {
    // ...
  },
  error: function(e) {
    // ...
  },
  // Form data
  data: formData,
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
});
```

Here would be the PHP code to save the file:

```
<?php
    $targetfile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfile);
?>
```

Note: The default POST content length is set to 8M in PHP and can be changed in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
if(move_uploaded_files($tmp_name,$location.'number,pdf')) {
    echo "uploaded!!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must realize that when PHP accepts an uploaded file, it automatically gives it a temporary name and stores it in your system's temporary directory.  So after uploading a file, you have to retrieve it's current, actual location.

```
$tmpFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

From here, you can use the `move_uploaded_file` function, to store it where you want and with the final filename you want.  So in your case, it would look something like this.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, '/path/to/uploads/directory/' . $_POST['number'] . '.pdf');
```

You will of course want to do your validation before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use javascript or client-side code to rename just before upload. Upload UI element  behavior is totally controlled by the browser unless you write a custom upload control on your own.

However, you can achieve the same goal of renaming the uploaded file on the server side.

```
$destDir = '/var/www/';   //can be any directory on your server, writeable by webserver

$renamedFilename = $_POST['number']; 
//keep the same file extension if uploaded file has it
$renamedFilename .= ($pos = strrpos($_FILES['file']['name'], '.')) === false ? '' : substr($_FILES['file']['name'], $pos);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $renamedFilename);
```